# Help understanding "Hen ngai cang hiau chut-theu" by Zhang Shaolin

Tags: translation, hakka

[张少林个“肯涯正晓出头”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCFjOG6a2tY)

人穷爱肯涯正晓出头
平时努力人系饿毋瘦
完家大细一大楸
来负担系好愁
早晨由暗做杉几十穷
涯到拨病骨头痛又
做到瘦
还惊饿死老婆屋又臭
做到 汗流
周时爱当借靠老朋友
年轻爱食苦 做事莫怕羞
出头个日子还有

Nyin khiung oi hen ngai tsang hiau chut-theu
Phin-sii nu-lit nyin he ngo m seu
Won ka thai-se yit thai chiu
Loi fu-tam he hau seu
Tsau-sin yu am tso sam ki sip khiung
Ngai tau pot-phiang kut-theu thung yiu
Tso tau siu
Han kiang ngo-si lau-pho wuk yiu chiu
Tso tau hon liu
Tsiu-sii oi tong cia khau lau phen-yiu
Nyien-khiang oi sit-khu tso-sii mok pha siu
Chut-theu ke nyit-tsii han yu

When poverty allows me, I will succeed
People who work hard in common times are not scarce in hunger
The whole family, young and old people, are a big tree
And holding it up is rather sad (?)
In the morning from when it's still dark I make clothes in the tens.
If I fall ill and my bones hurt, I still
Work till I'm thin
I still fear I'll starve to death and my wife abd my house will be poor again
I work till my sweat flows
I often have to rely on old friends for borrowing [stuff]
When you're young you must suffer work and not be afraid of disgrace
There will still be a day of success

The above is my character approximation, transliteration, and translation attempt for a Hakka song by Zhang Shaolin. I am unsure about the following:

1. Translating 愁 as sad is the only option given the character, but I would expect something more like "hard, difficult" than "sad"; is that correct, or is there another seu/siu which fits best? Or maybe 楸 is the wrong character?
2. Is my reading of 早晨由暗做杉几十穷 correct?
3. That 当借 feels a bit like it should be a single verb, but I can't find it; is my translation fine?

Any other inputs are of course welcome.

**EDIT**

The first line is extremely prone to misinterpretation, because:

1. 人穷 is reported by Minhakka… um, seems to be reported by Minhakka as "poverty", the culprit being «人窮起盗心», translated to «poverty leads to thievery» when a more literal (i.e. structure-reflecting) translation is «if a man is poor he will grow a thief's heart»;
2. 肯 also means "allow";
3. The sound "ngai" is, in my mind, automatically matched to the pronoun "ngâi", meaning "I"; however, it is also the verb 捱, meaning "to endure, to suffer".

So after clearing up point 1, only one option is left:

> 人穷爱肯捱正晓出头 | If a man is poor, only when he is willing to endure hardships will he succeed

With point 1 not cleared, the obvious interpretation is what I gave at the beginning. If we change the interpretation of 肯捱 without clearing up point 1, we end up with:

> 人穷爱肯捱正晓出头

interpreted as:

> Only when (正) [I] will (爱) be willing (肯) to endure (捱) [my] poverty (人穷) can (晓) [I] succeed (出头).

Comment: It should be 人穷爱肯[捱][至]晓出头

Comment: @TangHo concerning ngai, I follow the convention of the fb group Hakka Verse, which uses that character, and I also have a source with yet another radical (the person radical) suggested, so unless that is not the pronoun ngai I will keep that character. Concerning tsang, [Minhakka](minhakka.ling.sinica.edu.tw) actually supports my spelling for the word "chàng" meaning "just, exactly", and only reads 至 as chì, which is not what is heard in the song, so why should I use 至?

Comment: I agree with @tang ho , 肯`捱` is the proper term.  both 捱 and 涯 pronounce as ngai in hakka, this is Hans character, you cannot simply use 涯 because it pronounce the same.

Comment: @mootmoot On what basis are you suggesting I change the spelling of this pronoun?

Comment: Go check out zdic.net if you insist to use  涯. 
All the Chinese dialect are using the same unified mandrain character, you cannot simply redefine the meaning.

Comment: @mootmoot So now I have 3 dictionaries and one Facebook group with 4 different suggestions for this pronoun: [zdict](https://zdic.net), you say, suggests 捱, [Minhakka](https://minhakka.ling.sinica.edu.tw) suggests 我, [hakka.dict](https://hakka.dict.edu.tw) suggests (亻厓), and the Facebook group Hakka Verse (or at least its founder Anton Xie) uses 涯. «All the Chinese dialect» in what sense? I only use 涯 because my keyboard won't let me input the hakka.dict one, and because it appears as a square on some computers.

Comment: Also, inputting 捱 produces the explanation «put off, procrastinate; endure», so where does zdic suggest that character?

Comment: 涯 doesn't has the meaning of 捱(to endure) that's why you must choose 捱 in this context,  涯 is not even a verb

Comment: @TangHo So you are saying this "ngai" is not the Hakka pronoun "ngai" meaning "I" but a verb meaning "to endure"?

Comment: Yes "肯捱 "means "willing to endure"

Comment: 捱 is used interchangeably as “挨” , http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/6328.htm

Comment: @TangHo So what is l. 1 saying? «Only when [I] will be willing to endure poverty will [I] succeed»?

Comment: 人穷 (when a man is poor) 爱肯捱( you must be willing to endure hardship, meaning to  work hard) 正(only then) 晓(would) 出头(you succeed)

Comment: 如果你肯`挨/ 捱` , actually carry the meaning of `挨苦` : enduring the hard works. 
Philosophically,  I don't believe such, as serious poverty is an act of struggling to survive, it will not change one status without external helps.

Comment: My gosh that sentence has so many ambiguities! 人穷 is reported as meaning "poverty" on Minhakka, 肯 can mean "allow", "ngai" is a very-often-misspelt pronoun, leading me to a completely wrong reading of that sentence. Time to edit my question to address this issue.

Comment: ngai (I) should be written as 我

Comment: @TangHo On what basis should I create a duōyīnzì in Hakka when this pronoun is never spelt 我 in lyrics and both [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%8A%8E) and [hakka.dict](http://hakka.dict.edu.tw/hakkadict/index.htm) (search for ngai, it will appear) suggest ? If that only were inputable via keyboard and properly rendered on my mobile I would use it, but since I need a fallback I choose something that looks similar and doesn't cause pronunciation ambiguities, hence 涯.

Comment: @MickG In Cantonese, the verb "to come' is pronounced as "嚟" as in "返嚟" (come back)," 嚟搵人" (Come to look for someone), But  "嚟" is a colloquial word, the literary word  "to come" is still "來". Even  the noun "I" in Minhakka is pronounced as "涯" but the literary writing of "I" is still "我";  "涯" is a colloquial word that's being accepted as literary one, just like Cantonese accepting 嚟 as a  literary  word. but the original words are still "來"and "我"

Comment: @TangHo Well then, since the song is, I believe, written in a colloquial dialect and not meant to be literary, there is no need to use a literary word, and the colloquial one is more appropriate, right?

Comment: Also, I guess the ngai in line 6 should also be spelt the other way.

Comment: Is it possible that the "won ka", which I respelled 完家, was actually correct as 宛家?

Comment: @MickG I don't speak Minhakka, but 完家 (colloquial) sounds like 全家(literary ) to me. However, 完 has the meaning of "complete" therefore "完家" might also be a legit term (use in both colloquial and  literary) for "whole family" in Minhakka

Comment: @TangHo and that is exactly why I decided to write 完家 instead of the 宛家 I saw in the video's karaoke captiona. So do you think I was right in assuming the 宛 in the captions was just a phonetic loan or could it have a distinct meaning?

Comment: Yes I think 宛 is a phonetic loan sound for 完 (complete) ; 宛 itself doesn't carry any related meaning in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 来负担系好**愁** = to burden oneself is very **worrisome**

> 2. Is my reading of 早晨由暗做杉几十穷 correct?

It is not Mandarin or Cantonese,  I am not sure if your pinyin is correct or not, but sound like O.K to me.

3. 当= 典当 (to pawn); 借= to borrow. The two verbs together means "to pawn and borrow"

[周时][爱][当][借][靠老朋友]= Often pawn, borrow and rely on (support from) old friends

**Edit:**

MickG wrote:

> *Would I then be right in translating «完家大细一大楸 来负担系好愁» as «All my family, older and younger [people], is a big tree, and burdening myself [with it] is very worrysome»?*

完家大细 = the entire family (old and young) ; 一大楸 = a big bundle  来负担系好愁 = it is very worrisome to burden myself (with all of them)

"完家大细一大楸 来负担系好愁" means " the entire family old and young, is a big bundle, to burden (myself with it) is very worrisome"

Comment: The transliteration is an approximation of what I hear. In particular, the pairs c-ts, ch-tsh and sh-s may exhibit switchings w.r.t. Minhakka. The rest should be correct.

Comment: Would I then be right in translating «完家大细一大楸 来负担系好愁» as «All my family, older and younger [people], is a big tree, and burdening myself [with it] is very worrysome»?

Comment: See my edition at the bottom.

Comment: So it's using the name of a tree as a metaphor for a heavy burden. Does such a thing happen in Mandarin too or should I provide a gloss on a blog post where I gloss every non-Mandarin word with matching Mandarin translations?

Comment: `週時愛當借靠老朋友`  in Hakka has nothing to do with simply pawning or borrowing.  `愛` mean needs or `需要`,  當 has nothing to do with pawn， it should be read as 當借靠老朋友 , it means you should get help from your folks when in needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm transcribing this out of my memory from years ago.

人穷爱肯**挨**正晓出头 (same as 捱 endure -- i prefer 挨 as it's more common)
When you are poor, only by being able to endure can you succeed

平时努力人系饿毋瘦
Working hard daily, you might be hungry but not gaunt

完家大细一大**湊** or 潮
The whole family, big and small, a big group

来负担系好愁
Is a burden, really worrisome

早晨又暗做**三二十塊**
Morning and night working (for) 30-20 dollars

**挨**到**發**病骨头痛又做到瘦

The rest is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should settles it?

https://youtu.be/GrzCAlssHoI

BTW, for years this has been my favourite Hakka karaoke song.

There is also the "original" Hokkien version and a Cantonese version, though the lyrics of all 3 are different, they share the same general theme, i.e. "one has to work hard, endure hardships and not depend too much on mother luck to succeed in life"

Since I could sing all 3 versions, I put the Hokkien and Cantonese versions below for anyone interested.

Hokkien version"-

https://youtu.be/wflMFaDSJDo

Cantonese version:-

https://youtu.be/r5lFyMS1Mh8

Enjoy, I hope.

Comment: The hidden problem or linguistic trap when using one set of written Chinese characters to verbalize a certain dialect is that the dialect speakers merely borrows the "sound" of the Character and not its meaning. A good example is the very first line which has brought about much confusion and arguments for non-Hakka speakers, and it is the common "mandarin" word, 爱, as in  人穷爱肯捱 . A non-Hakka speaker would be forgiven for saying it means -- "A poor person loves to suffer or endure hardships..." The 爱 here dose not mean "love" or "have affection for", but means simply -- "be willing or need to"

Comment: Oh, BTW, when Hakkas write "love" they use "爱" as well.